# Writing data to a specific address in EEPROM

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom, data

I'm trying to write two strings to an Arduino Uno's EEPROM. Here, the first code block works fine: it writes string(True/False) at 'address 0'. But the second block, which writes data at 'address 5', is not working as expected.Reading data at address 5 prints a blank line. What am I missing here? Is this the correct way to write two different strings to EEPROM?

First code block:

```
int state = LOW;
char first_eeprom_value;
if (state == LOW) {
  state = HIGH;
  char example_string[4] = "True";
  first_eeprom_value = EEPROM.read(0);
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i, example_string[i]);
  }
} else {
  state = LOW;
  char example_string[5] = "False";
  first_eeprom_value = EEPROM.read(0);
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i, example_string[i]);
  }
}
Time = millis();
```

Second code block:

```
char first_eeprom_value1;
if (state1 == LOW) {
  state1 = HIGH;
  char example_string1[4] = "True";
  first_eeprom_value1 = EEPROM.read(5);      
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value1);
  for (int i = 5 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i, example_string1[i]);
  }
} else {
  state1 = LOW;
  char example_string1[5] = "False";
  first_eeprom_value1 = EEPROM.read(5);     
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value1);
  for (int i = 5 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i, example_string1[i]);
  }
}

Time = millis();

//reading data at address 5
int addr = 5;
char value = EEPROM.read(addr);
Serial.println(value);// this prints blank line
```

Comment: *is not working as expected* - what do you expect, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Nothing is getting written when using 2nd code block.

Comment: How do you know? Can you please amend your question to include the output from the serial prints that you have in your code?

Comment: I have edited the question and 2nd code block.

Comment: remove the `if ... then ... else` statements ... minimize the code as much as possible ... do just a write and then a read ... do you still have the same problem?

Comment: you do not terminate the strings with 0. for a string with 4 chars allocate an array of 5 chars and write 0 at the end after reading from eeprom.. otherwise the print doesn't know where the string ends

Comment: @Juraj Let me try that.

Comment: "you do not terminate the strings with 0"- Can u help me with code?

Comment: @Juraj he is reading just one char from the eeprom, not a string, so a terminator is not required

Comment: @frarugi87, true. the code is so chaotic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cycling outside the string, thus creating undefined behavior.

Try replacing the second block with this:

```
char first_eeprom_value1;
if (state1 == LOW) {
  state1 = HIGH;
  char example_string1[4] = "True";
  first_eeprom_value1 = EEPROM.read(5);      
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value1);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(example_string1); i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i + 5, example_string1[i]);
  }
} else {
  state1 = LOW;
  char example_string1[5] = "False";
  first_eeprom_value1 = EEPROM.read(5);     
  Serial.println(first_eeprom_value1);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(example_string1); i++) {
    EEPROM.update(i + 5, example_string1[i]);
  }
}
```

Please note that this is not optimal; I suggest you to use fixed-length strings, and fill the unused spaces with blanks or 0s, so you can read back all the bytes you wrote in a safe way